# How does one handle run time errors in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

```
try
    DISCONNECT;
    // Profile demo
    SQLCA.DBMS = "ODBC"
    SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
    SQLCA.DBParm = "ConnectString='DSN=demo;UID=;PWD='"
    CONNECT;

    tab_kava.tabpage_member.dw_kava_member.settransobject(sqlca)
    tab_kava.tabpage_member.dw_kava_member.retrieve()

catch(DWRuntimeError myExc)
   MessageBox ("DWRuntimeError", "Errortext")
end try
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  The dwRunTimeError class, (your "myExc" in this case), will contain error and diagnostic information.

For example, something like:

```
catch(DWRunTimeError myExc)
  messageBox( "DWRuntimeError", myExc.errorText )
```

You can also stack exception "catch" clauses, from most restrictive to most general, and the exception will be caught by the first one that it qualifies for.  You're using a DWRuntimeError - what if the error being thrown is just a RuntimeError?  Your existing clause would ignore it, and the systemerror event would trigger.

-Paul-

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    //your code
catch (runtimeerror  e)
    messagebox("Error",e.getMessage())
end try
```